# How can animate textures in a vertex array?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, vertex

So I have made a tile map class in sfml that uses a vertex array to build all of the tiles in the map. The whole thing just uses one texture for the whole map. How can I update the texture coordinates in the vertex array to make certain quads (like water tiles) animate? It would be nice not to update the vertex array every time I want it to switch frames.

It is similar to the tilemap here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-vertex-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly.

The only two options you have if you stick with a vertex array are:

1) Update the whole vertex array every frame.
2) Update just the vertices that are used for the water every frame.

In general it's best to just go with the way you can think of or you find the easiest to implement and if you run into performance issues, then start thinking on how you could optimizing things. In many cases it has been proven to be no issue at all.

Comment: Ok I think ill go with only updating animated tile vertices